# Are there any items which raise your maximum stats?

Tags: dont-starve

While poking about on the Don't Starve Wiki, I've seen a number of items that will lower the maximum stats for things like health or sanity.  (*e.g.* The Meat Effigy lowering maximum health)

Are there any items or companions that cause your maximum health/hunger/sanity to increase?

Comment: The game tells me I level up every time I die.

Comment: That has more to do with unlocking characters than upping your in-game stats.

Comment: Addendum to the existing answers: except for WX-78 and his gears, there are no items you can wear/build that raise your maximum stats. A special case is the **meat effigy**, which lowers your max health 30 points each time you build one.

Comment: And another special case is Maxwell's shadow puppet, lowering your max sanity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is only one character that can raise its maximum stats: WX-78, the robot. It can eat Gears, which upgrades its maximum health, hunger, and sanity with each Gear consumed. It can consume a maximum of 15 gears, to get 400 health, 200 hunger, and 300 sanity. (The bonus is 20 health, ~6.66 hunger, and ~13.33 sanity per gear, rounded up.)

WX-78 needs this pretty badly, because it starts with below-normal stats.

Comment: Also, WX is considered to be extremely OP when maxed out.

Comment: @Konerak sorry, I'm not familiar with the term OP. Can you clarify?

Comment: OP = overpowered.

Answer (score -2):

Booster shots!!! They increase your max health by 20. I believe it is 3 papyrus, 2 healing salve and a stinger, or at least that's what the wiki says.

Comment: Booster shoots are only avaible in the multiplayer version, i learn that the hard way, in front of the alchemy engine with lots of items to craft does shoots,,,,,,